# How to make a chained aggregation of a mongoDB collections with multiple local-field comparisons?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate

Here are my collections:

users:

```
{
    user: xxx,
    job: xxx,
    order: xxxx
}
```

cars:

```
{
    order: xxxx,
    cost: yyyy
}
```

plane:

```
{
    order: xxxx,
    cost: yyyy
}
```

insurance:

```
{
    cost: yyyy,
    terms: zzzz
}
```

First, I want to join "users" with either of "cars" or "planes" based on matching the value of "order" field. Afterward, I join the result with the "insurance" collection based on the "cost" field.

So, I want the result to like this:

```
{ "user" : xx, ..., "order": dsad, "cars": {}, "plane": {"order": ddsa, "cost": awew} , "terms": sdada},
{ "user" : yy, ..., "order": sawe, "cars": {"order": fda, "cost": qwez}, "plane": {} , "terms": tyrw},
{ "user" : zz, ..., "order": qwez, "cars": {}, "plane": {} , "terms":{} }
```

I tried using db.users.aggregate() along with $lookup as below:

```
db.check.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "cars",
            localField: "order",
            foreignField: "order",
            as: "cars"
        }    
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$cars", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},    
{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "planes",
            localField: "order",
            foreignField: "order",
            as: "planes"
        }    
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$planes", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},
```

and it results in:

```
{ "user" : xx, ..., "order": dsad, "cars": {}, "plane": {"order": ddsa, "cost": awew}},
{ "user" : yy, ..., "order": sawe, "cars": {"order": fda, "cost": qwez}, "plane": {}},
{ "user" : zz, ..., "order": qwez, "cars": {}, "plane": {}}
```

but, I do not know to go further from there!

Comment: what is the matching criteria for your join?

Comment: what else do you want to do that you are not able to?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti First, I want to join "users" with either of "cars" or "planes" based on matching the value of "order" field. Afterward, I join the result with the "insurance" collection based on the "cost" field. 
I cannot do the last join (insurance) based on comparing "cost" to results form either cars or planes!

Comment: either cars cost or plane cost should match, is that what you want?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti Yes!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get what you want.

Try this :

```
db.check.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "cars",
            localField: "order",
            foreignField: "order",
            as: "cars"
        }    
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$cars", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},    
{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "planes",
            localField: "order",
            foreignField: "order",
            as: "planes"
        }    
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$planes", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},{
    $lookup:{
        from : "insurance",
        let  : {
            carCost : "$cars.cost",
            planeCost : "$planes.cost"
        },
        pipeline : [{
            $match : {
                $expr :{
                    $or : [{
                        cost : "$$carCost" 
                    },{
                        cost : "$$planeCost"
                    }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }],
        as : "insurance"
    }
},{
    $unwind: {path: "$insurance", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},{
    $project : {
        user:1,
        order:1,
        cars:1,
        planes:1,
        terms : "$insurance.terms"
    }
}]
```

Comment: do you want all the terms or only the first one? or how do you want to match?